# Can G-suite admins see browsing history when im using an onion browser

Tags: onion-routing

Couldnt find any answers online. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of the permissions your G-Suite admins have on your device if they do?

Answer (score 1):

As HackerNCoder stated, if the G-Suite admins can access your device, then they can almost certainly see your browsing history. They can install software to monitor your usage of the Onion browser. They control your device and you can't stop them.

However, if they only have access to your google account, then you are probably anonymous. I would recommend not logging though (obviously, they can see what you are doing on google services if you are logged in while using the Onion browser).

Comment: Unless you have a custom Android OS with proper security **added** - there's not enough tools to do so just out of the AOSP source code box, but the building system is flexible and you can do a lot of custom mods yourself

Answer (score 0):

If they have access to your computer/device (e.g. it's a computer they handed out that may have spyware installed). Yes.

Else no.